# Reverse the order between year and days in a datetime vector

Tags: r, datetime, posixct

I have some raw data

```
po59<-structure(list(case_id = c("WC4120721", "WC4120667", "WC4120689", 
"WC4121068", "WC4120667", "WC4120666", "WC4120667", "WC4121068", 
"WC4120667", "WC4121068", "WC4121068", "WC4120666", "WC4120721", 
"WC4120666", "WC4120666"), lifecycle = c(110, 110, 110, 110, 
120, 110, 130, 120, 10, 130, 10, 120, 120, 130, 10), action = c("WC4120721-CN354877", 
"WC4120667-CN354878", "WC4120689-CN356752", "WC4121068-CN301950", 
"WC4120667-CSW310", "WC4120666-CN354878", "WC4120667-CSW308", 
"WC4121068-CSW303", "WC4120667-CSW309", "WC4121068-CSW308", "WC4121068-CSW309", 
"WC4120666-CSW310", "WC4120721-CSW310", "WC4120666-CSW308", "WC4120666-CSW309"
), activity = c("Forged Wire, Medium (Sport)", "Forged Wire, Medium (Sport)", 
"Forged Wire, Medium (Sport)", "Forged Wire, Medium (Sport)", 
"BBH-1&2", "Forged Wire, Medium (Sport)", "TCE Cleaning", "SOLO Oil", 
"Tempering", "TCE Cleaning", "Tempering", "BBH-1&2", "BBH-1&2", 
"TCE Cleaning", "Tempering"), resource = c("3419", "3216", "3409", 
"3201", "C3-100", "3216", "C3-080", "C3-030", "C3-090", "C3-080", 
"C3-090", "C3-100", "C3-100", "C3-080", "C3-090"), timestamp = c("03.12.20 6:00", 
"04.12.20 23:58", "08.12.20 16:56", "10.12.20 5:42", "10.12.20 22:57", 
"11.12.20 10:13", "11.12.20 14:17", "11.12.20 21:20", "12.12.20 2:32", 
"12.12.20 6:35", "12.12.20 14:50", "14.12.20 13:50", "14.12.20 19:11", 
"15.12.20 1:10", "15.12.20 9:25")), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Then I convert to `bupaR` object with:

```
po59br<-bupaR::eventlog(eventlog = po59,
                       case_id = "case_id",
                       activity_id = "activity",
                       activity_instance_id = "action",
                       lifecycle_id = "lifecycle",
                       timestamp = "timestamp",
                       resource_id = "resource"
 )
```

and I try to give the datetime data a format like : `2020-12-03 06:00:00` instead of `0003-12-20 06:00:00`

```
po59$timestamp<-as.POSIXct(po59$timestamp,format="%Y.%m.%d 
%H:%M",tz=Sys.timezone())
```

Comment: `attr(times2$timestamp, "tzone") <- "UTC"` for normalizing the different time zones. However, either you're referencing a very different time period (0003 AD versus 2017 AD) or your second timestamps were imported/converted improperly.

Comment: times2$timestamp<-attr(times2$timestamp, "tzone") <- "UTC" just replaces everything with "UTC". For example the 1st one should be converted to "2020-12-03 06:00:00"

Comment: Yep, that's why I said that normalizes the different time zones. Are you saying that the `0003-` of the date is incorrect?

Comment: Its the 3rd day of the month but it has to be displayed like 2020-12-03 instead of 0003-12-20

Comment: So my first comment still stands: the data was imported incorrectly the first time. Due to the potential for data-loss, you should not be trying to "convert" a `POSIXt` object from `"0003-12-20"` to `"2020-12-03"`, you really need to go back to the raw data and convert it to `POSIXt` correctly the first time.

Comment: you can check on my edit

Comment: Your edit doesn't clarify anything, it's just more rows showing the same problem. Perhaps go earlier in your code-chain to find where you are converting from `character` to `POSIXt`, and provide both the pre-conversion data sample and the code you're using to convert it.

Comment: Or I should clarify ... how are you creating `production_operation_59`? Do you get it from a single function call somewhere that is already converting string to timestamp?

Comment: sorry I edited regarding the initial dataset

Comment: Do you have a version of sample data where `timestamp` is of class `character`, _not yet converted_ to class `POSIXt`?

Comment: ok just edited now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before and after:

```r
po59$timestamp
#  [1] "03.12.20 6:00"  "04.12.20 23:58" "08.12.20 16:56" "10.12.20 5:42"  "10.12.20 22:57" "11.12.20 10:13" "11.12.20 14:17"
#  [8] "11.12.20 21:20" "12.12.20 2:32"  "12.12.20 6:35"  "12.12.20 14:50" "14.12.20 13:50" "14.12.20 19:11" "15.12.20 1:10" 
# [15] "15.12.20 9:25" 

as.POSIXct(po59$timestamp, format="%d.%m.%y %H:%M")
#  [1] "2020-12-03 06:00:00 EST" "2020-12-04 23:58:00 EST" "2020-12-08 16:56:00 EST" "2020-12-10 05:42:00 EST"
#  [5] "2020-12-10 22:57:00 EST" "2020-12-11 10:13:00 EST" "2020-12-11 14:17:00 EST" "2020-12-11 21:20:00 EST"
#  [9] "2020-12-12 02:32:00 EST" "2020-12-12 06:35:00 EST" "2020-12-12 14:50:00 EST" "2020-12-14 13:50:00 EST"
# [13] "2020-12-14 19:11:00 EST" "2020-12-15 01:10:00 EST" "2020-12-15 09:25:00 EST"
```

This is what should be done when you first read in and process this data, in place of any other conversion you have on `timestamp`:

```r
po59$timestamp <- as.POSIXct(po59$timestamp, format="%d.%m.%y %H:%M")
po59
# # A tibble: 15 x 6
#    case_id   lifecycle action             activity                    resource timestamp               
#    <chr>         <dbl> <chr>              <chr>                       <chr>    <dttm>                  
#  1 WC4120721       110 WC4120721-CN354877 Forged Wire, Medium (Sport) 3419     2020-12-03 06:00:00.0000
#  2 WC4120667       110 WC4120667-CN354878 Forged Wire, Medium (Sport) 3216     2020-12-04 23:58:00.0000
#  3 WC4120689       110 WC4120689-CN356752 Forged Wire, Medium (Sport) 3409     2020-12-08 16:56:00.0000
#  4 WC4121068       110 WC4121068-CN301950 Forged Wire, Medium (Sport) 3201     2020-12-10 05:42:00.0000
#  5 WC4120667       120 WC4120667-CSW310   BBH-1&2                     C3-100   2020-12-10 22:57:00.0000
#  6 WC4120666       110 WC4120666-CN354878 Forged Wire, Medium (Sport) 3216     2020-12-11 10:13:00.0000
#  7 WC4120667       130 WC4120667-CSW308   TCE Cleaning                C3-080   2020-12-11 14:17:00.0000
#  8 WC4121068       120 WC4121068-CSW303   SOLO Oil                    C3-030   2020-12-11 21:20:00.0000
#  9 WC4120667        10 WC4120667-CSW309   Tempering                   C3-090   2020-12-12 02:32:00.0000
# 10 WC4121068       130 WC4121068-CSW308   TCE Cleaning                C3-080   2020-12-12 06:35:00.0000
# 11 WC4121068        10 WC4121068-CSW309   Tempering                   C3-090   2020-12-12 14:50:00.0000
# 12 WC4120666       120 WC4120666-CSW310   BBH-1&2                     C3-100   2020-12-14 13:50:00.0000
# 13 WC4120721       120 WC4120721-CSW310   BBH-1&2                     C3-100   2020-12-14 19:11:00.0000
# 14 WC4120666       130 WC4120666-CSW308   TCE Cleaning                C3-080   2020-12-15 01:10:00.0000
# 15 WC4120666        10 WC4120666-CSW309   Tempering                   C3-090   2020-12-15 09:25:00.0000
```

---

Data

```r
po59 <- structure(list(case_id = c("WC4120721", "WC4120667", "WC4120689", "WC4121068", "WC4120667", "WC4120666", "WC4120667", "WC4121068", "WC4120667", "WC4121068", "WC4121068", "WC4120666", "WC4120721", "WC4120666", "WC4120666"), lifecycle = c(110, 110, 110, 110, 120, 110, 130, 120, 10, 130, 10, 120, 120, 130, 10), action = c("WC4120721-CN354877", "WC4120667-CN354878", "WC4120689-CN356752", "WC4121068-CN301950", "WC4120667-CSW310", "WC4120666-CN354878", "WC4120667-CSW308", "WC4121068-CSW303", "WC4120667-CSW309",  "WC4121068-CSW308", "WC4121068-CSW309", "WC4120666-CSW310", "WC4120721-CSW310", "WC4120666-CSW308", "WC4120666-CSW309"), activity = c("Forged Wire, Medium (Sport)", "Forged Wire, Medium (Sport)", "Forged Wire, Medium (Sport)", "Forged Wire, Medium (Sport)", "BBH-1&2", "Forged Wire, Medium (Sport)", "TCE Cleaning", "SOLO Oil", "Tempering", "TCE Cleaning", "Tempering", "BBH-1&2", "BBH-1&2", "TCE Cleaning", "Tempering"), resource = c("3419", "3216", "3409", "3201", "C3-100", "3216", "C3-080", "C3-030",  "C3-090", "C3-080", "C3-090", "C3-100", "C3-100", "C3-080", "C3-090"), timestamp = c("03.12.20 6:00", "04.12.20 23:58", "08.12.20 16:56", "10.12.20 5:42", "10.12.20 22:57", "11.12.20 10:13", "11.12.20 14:17", "11.12.20 21:20", "12.12.20 2:32", "12.12.20 6:35", "12.12.20 14:50", "14.12.20 13:50", "14.12.20 19:11", "15.12.20 1:10", "15.12.20 9:25")), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the library `lubridate` to fix your dates.

Starting with the data structured exactly as it is in your question, `update` them by switching the year and date. (Add the 2K back to the year, as well.)

```
library(lubridate)

po59$timestamp <- update(po59$timestamp,
                         year = 2000 + day(po59$timestamp),
                         day = year(po59$timestamp))
head(po59)
# # A tibble: 6 × 6
#   case_id   lifecycle action             activity    resou…¹ timestamp          
#   <chr>         <dbl> <chr>              <chr>       <chr>   <dttm>             
# 1 WC4120721       110 WC4120721-CN354877 Forged Wir… 3419    2020-12-03 06:00:00
# 2 WC4120667       110 WC4120667-CN354878 Forged Wir… 3216    2020-12-04 23:58:00
# 3 WC4120689       110 WC4120689-CN356752 Forged Wir… 3409    2020-12-08 16:56:00
# 4 WC4121068       110 WC4121068-CN301950 Forged Wir… 3201    2020-12-10 05:42:00
# 5 WC4120667       120 WC4120667-CSW310   BBH-1&2     C3-100  2020-12-10 22:57:00
# 6 WC4120666       110 WC4120666-CN354878 Forged Wir… 3216    2020-12-11 10:13:00
```